Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler'
I am trying to install Vue dependencies globally on my machine instead of relying on a local setup. My goal is to manually install only the necessary modules globally. However, I am struggling to resolve the error: "Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler'", even though I have installed it.
I have come across solutions suggesting that both vue and vue-template-compiler must have matching versions, which I have ensured in my local setup. This approach works perfectly in my local environment, but when I attempt the same in a global setup, the error persists.
Here is what I mean by local setup and global setup:
Local setup: Installing all dependencies specific to a project within its directory using npm install in /workspaces/node_modules.
Global setup: Installing only essential dependencies globally on the machine using npm install -g, to avoid tying the dependencies to a single project directory in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.
In my local setup, the following modules are installed:
/workspaces
├── @babel/core@7.26.0
├── @babel/eslint-parser@7.25.9
├── @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.8
├── @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
├── @vue/cli-plugin-router@5.0.8
├── @vue/cli-service@5.0.8
├── axios@1.7.7
├── bootstrap-vue@2.23.1
├── bootstrap@5.3.3
├── core-js@3.39.0
├── eslint-config-prettier@8.10.0
├── eslint-plugin-prettier@4.2.1
├── eslint-plugin-vue@8.7.1
├── eslint@7.32.0
├── keycloak-js@25.0.6
├── prettier@2.8.8
├── vue-multiselect@3.1.0
├── vue-router@3.6.5
├── vue-template-compiler@2.7.16
└── vue@2.7.16

In my global setup, I have installed only the following modules:
/usr/local/lib
├── @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.8 extraneous
├── @vue/cli-service@5.0.8 extraneous
├── vue-multiselect@3.1.0 extraneous
├── vue-template-compiler@2.7.16 extraneous
└── vue@2.7.16 extraneous

I am relatively new to application development and want to install only the essential dependencies globally to set up the frontend. My plan is to package these dependencies for deployment on another machine, which cannot use the standard method of running npm install -g. While I can install and package the dependencies in the project locally, I am keen to understand why this global approach is not working.

Consider explaining your case. It's unclear how you try to use the packages globally. It looks like there's a misunderstanding what global deps are for. They are to provide commandline binaries. It makes no sense to install other ones like vue, vue-template-compiler with -g

Hi, thank you for replying. My aim is to package all the npm dependencies I am using for my frontend and install them on a machine which can't use npm insallations for proxy reasons. When I install those packages locally in the project directory, it works fine.
Could you elaborate why it's not a good choice to install modules like vue, vue-template-compiler globally? I am new to it and I assumed it'd be helpful for future users such that they don't have to go through the same steps of using fpm packaging. Thanks!

It's not just not a good choice, this is just not how it works. Global deps are for cli commands. If you use a dep in a project, it needs to be installed to a project. If you have problems with offline then consider reasking the question and describing your situation, because this is XY problem. The deps can be installed from npm cache or something else. You can transfer node_modules from another machine but it won't work if there are platform-dependent packages

Are you using turbo for workspace management?
